# Medium breakpoint not working in Foundation 6

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, breakpoints

I switched from bootstrap 4 to foundation 6 last week. So maybe it's due to my lack of experience with foundation.

But I have a problem with my breakpoints. The small breakpoint is never working. It is always showing the medium breakpoint. Here is an example of my code and a screenshot of the page I am making at width 320px.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWWI.jpg)

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <section class="section">
    <h1 class="text-center">{{ entry.title }}</h1>
    <p class="text-center">{{ entry.subtext }}</p>

    <div class="grid-x activities">
        {% for activiteit in entry.activiteiten %}
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 cell">
            <div class="activity-card padding-2" style="background-color: {{ activiteit.kleurActiviteit }};">
                <div class="activity-card__image text-center">
                    <div style="background-image: url({{ activiteit.activiteitafbeelding.first().getUrl() }});"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="activity-card__title text-center">
                    <h2>{{ activiteit.title }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="activity-card__subtext">
                    <p class="text-center">{{ activiteit.korteTekst }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question. Had to set viewport meta tag in my html header.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```